# how to use accesskey in html

Tags: html, forms

I want my form to automatically switch from the username field to the password field as the user types in their information. I would also like the form to automatically submit when the user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

How would I do this with HTML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need javascript for that:

```
var el = document.getElementById('field_id');

el.onkeypress = function(event){
  var key = event.keycode || event.which;

  if (key === 13) {
     document.FormName.submit();
  }
};
```

**jQuery:** (based on comment)

```
$(function(){
    $('#form_id:input').keypress(function(event){
      var key = event.keycode || event.which;

      if (key === 13) {
         $(this).parents('form').submit();
      }

    });
});
```

Comment: @ sarfaraz are you convert it to jquery

Answer (score 2):

Example-

```
<FORM action="..." method="post">
<P>
<LABEL for="fuser" accesskey="U">
User Name
</LABEL>
<INPUT type="text" name="user" id="fuser">
</P>
</FORM>
```

See details [HERE](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/accesskey.html)

Answer (score 1):

(http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/index_famsupp_157.html)

this probably would help ;)

Comment: The link you provided is currently flagged as containing malware in both FF9 and in Google search.

Comment: It's not mine, and it's 2 years old :P but I just access the link without any problems,

Comment: Well, that comment was 2 moths old, so thanks for remarking the change :)